# Facebook payment dialog hides flash content E11

Tags: facebook, flash, internet-explorer

I've found strange behavior of facebook payment dialog in IE11 for app with Flash object that works with Context3D.

For case, when your FB app is working as flash-object (with `{ wmode: "direct" }`) in HTML canvas, FB SDK hides your flash object. Basically, "direct" wmode allows app to stream their graphics directly into "monitor" (if tell in short). So, before showing any other content this block should be hided. Thats why FB dialogs (notification, invites, payment dialogs, etc) should hide flash.

But, if you want to check payment in **IE11**, your flash object will be hidden, and will never get visible back.

Flash object embedded with swfobject v2.2:

```
swfobject.embedSWF(
    cfg.preloader_path,
    cfg.flashID,
    755,
    650,
    '11.0.0',
    'expressInstall.swf',
    { key: "val" },
    { "wmode" : "direct", "quality" : "high", "bgcolor" : "#ffffff" },
    { id: cfg.flashObjectId, name: cfg.flashObjectId, align: "middle" },
    function (swf) {
        if (swf.success) {
            console.log('Embedded successfully');
            // some staff here
        } else {
            console.log('Embedding failed');
        }
    });
```

App using FB API v2.X

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found way to fix this problem (but I think compatibility mode for IE is not a "clear" fix) is adding compatible meta-tag for IE:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE10" />
```

**UPD**

A lot of tests has showed me, that the problem is partially solved for IE11. Perhaps it depends on Flash Plugin version. I'm trying to find all dependencies.

**UPD**

I've found that even versions of Flash plugin in IE is correctly process that case, instead of odd versions (15,17,19) breaks it down.